# Office 2010 hangs in Win 7 box

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2010

Situation, testing Windows 7 box in workplace environment. Our current architecture is XP Pro running off server 2003 sbs. I have attached a windows 7 box with a trail version of Office 2010. My problem is I'm getting Outlook hangs which not only won't clear using task manager, but won't even allow a clean logoff. Having to hard boot computer to get back up and running. The triggers for these hangs are random, so I can't reproduce in a controlled test. The triggers also come from random areas, but all do with Office products. Some triggers(Assume Outlook is open in all cases) 1. Open Word document from email attachment. 2. Open Excel file from a network resource outside of Outlook. 3. Just opening an email message. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Office, I have disabled all unneeded addins. I haven't run in safe mode just because its totally random, and may happen anywhere from daily to 3 or 4 days apart.
Here is an example of the log entry:

> Event Type:   Error
> Event Source: Application Hang
> Event Category:   (101)
> Event ID: 1002
> Date:     4/1/2013
> Time:     12:02:55 PM
> User:     N/A
> Computer: xxxx
> Description:
> Hanging application OUTLOOK.EXE, version 14.0.6131.5000, hang module c40, version 01.., > hang address 0x60000.
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at ***.go.microsoft.com/fwlink

Any other thoughts on where to go with this one?

edit: Just some more info that may be pertinent. To accommodate an old version of Maximizer, I am running 32 bit Office on Win 7 64 bit.

Comment: Were office and Windows clean installs or upgrades?

Comment: Both were clean installs

Answer (score 1):

May be help ... Run

```
outlook /resetnavpane
```

Close Outlook.

Outlook 2010 disable word as email editor, way 2:

[How e-mail message formats affect Internet e-mail messages in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290809/en)

For Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013:

To turn off TNEF, follow these steps:

1. Open a new mail message, or click Reply on a received message.
2. On the Format Text tab, click HTML or Plain Text.

Comment: will try this, but can't get to computer at the moment as staff involved is busy

Comment: I understand were you are going with this, but the one time this crash triggered it had nothing whatsoever to do with email. The staff literally just opened an Excel file from a network folder. Albeit it was Outlook that reported the hang. Would this not exclude any text format trains of thought?

Comment: Is there any limitations to the 30 day trial period for Office software? As this is just a test box to see if this configuration would work in our office environment, I did not see the need to purchase a full Office suite yet.

Comment: @JodyReed Is not a Office 2010 problem. I think there is a problem on your workstations and networks, so you're lucky you were able to indirectly detect. Yes, the settings range Office confused and a bit unstable in the system plan. But it's good. Usually they do not cause problems. I suggest you refer to a good IT specialists to avoid losses in the future. Good luck!

Comment: I tried disabling indexing on pst/ost files, but this didn't appear to help. I have also moved archive file back to the local machine from the network. I haven't had a hang in a couple days after doing that. May definitely be something in how Outlook communicates with archives over network... I am still confused in regards to the one instance where the file opened was not part of Outlook. Could have been a red herring or maybe miscommunication from staff I have using this box.

Comment: Moving archive locally definitely helped, had one crash in a week, rather than 1-2 daily. Not perfect, but definitely an improvement.

Comment: Decommissioned this Windows box for now, more of a test situation. May pick it up again at a later date, but chances are when that happens, we will be upgrading more than just the client machines.